# Returning a value from recursive function that searches through JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I can't wrap my head around this problem! I'm using the following code to get a JSON file into a readable format in python:

```
jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFile.read())
x = self.searchJSON('search_term', jsonDict)
```

And then using this recursive function to loop through the dictionary to find the key I need.

```
def searchJSON(self, searchTerm, di=None):
    for k in di:
        if k == searchTerm:
            return di[k]
        if isinstance(k, dict):
            self.searchJSON(searchTerm, k)
        elif isinstance(k, list):
            self.searchJSON(searchTerm, k[0])
        elif isinstance(di[k], list) or isinstance(di[k], dict):
            self.searchJSON(searchTerm, di[k])
```

Using this, I can find the value that I'm looking for - no problem.. but I need to return the value back outside the function.

When I add returns:

```
def searchJSON(self, searchTerm, di=None):
    for k in di:
        if k == searchTerm:
            return di[k]
        if isinstance(k, dict):
            return self.searchJSON(searchTerm, k)
        elif isinstance(k, list):
            return self.searchJSON(searchTerm, k[0])
        elif isinstance(di[k], list) or isinstance(di[k], dict):
            return self.searchJSON(searchTerm, di[k])
```

The function stop running when it runs into an empty list. I spent a full day trying to figure this out, and this is the closest I've been able to get to returning the value.

Comment: if your function can't handle empty lists, it couldn't possibly do anything when it encounters one. I know this is not very helpful but when it comes to recursion, you should always have a well defined base case(s). In this case, empty list seems to be a base case for when your `k` is a list. But what is `di`? Is that a dictionary? because you can't use `list` as keys of a dictionary

Comment: Yes, basically your function always had a bug in it, and you didn't know it yet.  The answer posted below shows how to fix it.

Comment: When the function is first called, `di` is the JSON file represented as a list. So it contains lists, dictionaries, and some empty keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this out (Updated):**

```
def searchJSON(self, searchTerm, di=None):

    for k in di:
        if k == searchTerm:
            return di[k]

        if isinstance(k, dict):
            return self.searchJSON(searchTerm, k)

        elif isinstance(k, list):
            if k:
                return self.searchJSON(searchTerm, k[0])
            else:
                pass

        elif isinstance(di[k], list) or isinstance(di[k], dict):
            if di[k]:
                return self.searchJSON(searchTerm, di[k])
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I think the place it's stopping at is the last `elif` statement, because it's checking if the value of the key which holds the empty list - and then passing on the empty list.

Comment: I used your suggestion though, and put `if di[k] .... else: pass` and that fixed it.